# creating a touch slider using hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, hammer.js

To give you a little background I have been working with phonegap and jquery mobile to create a native mobile app. When using the JQUI the response on android devices seems VERY slow. In previous apps I have created my own tap events etc.

I recently found hammer.js...which is a super light touch library. Using this touch library GREATLY improves response on android devices.

With that back-story I have created a touch slider that calculates the time as you drag the knob.

I would like to step the slider by increments (I can't seem to figure out how to do this). In this case i need the slider to step in increments of 15mins. Right now the slider is stepping every min. I have been thinking about it for awhile now and I am lost. 
(here is an example of a increment step slider by JQ mobile http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/slider/ ...I am looking for something like this)

Here is my current code:
http://jsfiddle.net/cj8Hr/1/

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
        var calcMins = Math.round(left * pixelPerMin);
```

To

```
        var calcMins1 = Math.round(left * pixelPerMin);
        var calcMins = calcMins1 - (calcMins1 % 15);
```

Please check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cj8Hr/2/) .